# Script with Move-Item: "Cannot find part of the path" (Script Debug)

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a script that will find all files matching a string, and move them while re-creating the folder structure and renaming them if a file with the same name already exists. Problem is, I'm getting the dreaded "cannot find part of the path" error. I've found a workaround of sorts, but I'm guessing there's a better/"proper" way and I wanted to see where I was going wrong. Here's what I have:

```
$sourceDir = "E:\Folder1"
$targetDir = "E:\Deep Storage\Folder1"
$search = "*readme.txt*"

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir -Filter $search -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $relativePath = $_.FullName.Substring($sourceDir.Length)
    $nextName = Join-Path -Path $targetDir -ChildPath $relativePath

    $num = 1
    while(Test-Path -Path $nextName)
    {
       $nextName = Join-Path $targetDir ($relativePath + "_$num" + $_.Extension)    
       $num += 1   
    }

    $_ | Move-Item -Destination $nextName -Force -Verbose
}
```

The workaround that I have is to run this first:

```
robocopy $sourceDir $targetDir /e /xf *.*
```

I know Move-Item has a problem if the destination folder doesn't exist, but I don't know how to tell Powershell to create the destination directory if necessary. My workaround uses Robocopy to re-create the directory structure from the source directory to make Move-Item happy. Problem being, the Robocopy route takes forever.

I have another script that specifically creates folders, so this may be the answer, but I'm not sure how to blend this with the code I already have:

```
If(!(test-path $targetDir))
{
      New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $targetDir
}
```

Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Lots of mysterious, unassigned variables there! :D   You're wanting to recreate the folder structure of your source in the target directory, correct?

Comment: Actually, since you're moving rather them copying, you can just move the top level subfolders with their contents using move item with the dash recursed parameter. Provided of course, you don't want the source folders structure maintain ed..

Comment: I did forget to add the variable definitions, my fault. Happens when you get to be my age.

Comment: Yes, I do want to preserve the folder structure from the source to the destination, but not the whole directory structure--just where it finds files defined by $search. No sense creating a bunch of empty folders (Robocopy does that for me, but it takes forever, and I'm pretty sure there's a proper way to get Powershell to do what I'm asking).

Comment: And I can't just move the top level subfolder because that would take *all* the files, and I'm just looking to clear out specific files as defined by $search.

Comment: Realized that after I got off the bus and was focused on walking rather than my phone.... :D

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but this should get you close. I omitted the numbering becasue that would only be needed if items from multiple locations were being moved/copied to a single location and there was a chance of "...already exists..." errors.

```
$sourceDir       = "E:\Folder1"
$targetRoot      = "E:\Deep Storage\Folder1"
$search          = "*readme.txt*"

$relPathOffSet   = $sourceDir.Length
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir -Filter $search -Recurse | ForEach {
    $TargetPath  = Join-Path $targetRoot $_.FullName.SubString($relPathOffSet)
    $targetDir   = Split-Path $TargetPath
    If ( ! ( Test-Path($targetDir) ))
    {
         mkdir $targetDir -Force
    }
    $_ | Move-Item -Destination $TargetPath
}
```